# D3 change color based on node name

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a zoomable sunburst using D3 and now I would like to change the colors. I am visualizing some log data and so it has `success` and error codes like `BAERROR001` or `BAERROR002`. I would like to color the success part in green and the errors in shades of red. By default, the following code is used to pick color

```
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(d3.quantize(d3.interpolateRdYlGn, data.children.length + 1));
```

and

```
 const path = g.append("g")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(root.descendants().slice(1))
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("fill", d => { while (d.depth > 1) d = d.parent; return color(d.data.name); })
        .attr("fill-opacity", d => arcVisible(d.current) ? (d.children ? 0.6 : 0.4) : 0)
        .attr("d", d => arc(d.current));
```

For success my node has the name success and for the errors, it will be the corresponding error code. I am trying with categorical colors, but it is not working as expected. The code I am using is as follows :

```
 var color = d3.scaleOrdinal().domain([1, 10])
        .range(["green", "red"])
```

How can I select the color according to the `name` that has been passed ?

Comment: Can you please create a jsfiddle of your code ?

Comment: https://bl.ocks.org/EfratVil/903d82a7cde553fb6739fe55af6103e2